# Javascript test for blur event

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm working with knockout. i'm trying to test for enter key press OR blur event.

HTML:

```
<input class="percent-text" data-bind="numeric: Percent, value: Percent, event: { keypress: $root.percentUpdate, blur: $root.percentUpdate }" type="number" min="1" max="100" oninput="maxlength(this)" maxlength="3" />
```

knockout model:

```
self.percentUpdate = function (data, event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 13 || TEST FOR BLUR HERE) {
....
```

not sure how to test for blur event. help
thanks

Comment: So are you just checking if the event is firing? Or do you need to be able to differentiate in the final code?

Comment: if event is firing. I tried this but it doesn't work: event.target.status == 'blur'

Comment: do you want to check for `event.type === 'blur'` ? is that the question?

Comment: What does the `numeric` binding do?

Comment: allows you to only enter numerical values into a text box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not familiar with knockout, but I assume regular JavaScript will work:

```
self.percentUpdate = function (data, event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.type==='blur') {
```

Comment: You might have guessed it: That works, but isn't the idiomatic way to solve this problem in knockout.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just extra functions:

```
<input class="percent-text" data-bind="numeric: Percent, value: Percent, event: { keypress: $root.keypress, blur: $root.blur }" type="number" min="1" max="100" oninput="maxlength(this)" maxlength="3" />
```

and:

```
self.keypress = function(data, event){
  self.percentUpdate(data, 'keypress', event.keyCode);
};
self.blur = function(data){
  self.percentUpdate(data, 'blur');
}

self.percentUpdate = function (data, event, keyCode) {
            if (event === 'blur' && keyCode === 13) {
            ...}
```